# MSaccess where query between two tables with wildcards

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two Tables in an MS Access Database.

---

**Tickets** - is a linked SQL database table with three fields

Tickets.ID

Tickets.ticketnumber

Tickets.description - This is a memo field

---

**email** - is a local table with two fields

email.ID

email.eaddresses - this is a text field

---

What I need help doing is to get as a result of a query, a list of ticket numbers where an email address from email.eaddresses is in a Tickets.description field.

The tickets.description field can be very long with lots of information so I would assume the query would need to do some type of wrapping on the email addresses pulled from email.eaddresses like *email@email.com*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the following query.

```
SELECT email.eaddresses, Tickets.description
FROM Tickets, email
WHERE ((([Tickets]![description]) Like "*" & [email]![eaddresses] & "*"));
```